# Robot Framework Extending Selenium To Handle Loading Element

Tags: python, selenium, automation, frameworks, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework to do test automation and would like to know if there is a way for me to extend the Selenium Webdriver to handle a loading element universally. For reference when I say loading element I am referring to a custom Angular element.

I understand that I can do a `Wait Until Element Not Visible`, but what I really want to do is create a constant listener on the Selenium Webdriver to halt whenever this loading element is visible. I would like to not constantly use a robot keyword to check if the element is visible, and be forced to implement arbitrary-ish sleeps.

If my question is still not clear, below is some pseudocode / psuedoflow I was thinking of. I'm assuming Selenium is single threaded, otherwise this idea would be fruitless.

```
Selenium Webdriver:
       AddListener(new LoadingListener)

       LoadingListener
           While ( LoadingElement is Visible)
             Sleep 1s
```

Please respond with any feedback. If this isn't possible let me know, If you have any ideas also let me know.

Comment: Is this "loading element" something that is static (ie: has a consistent id or can be referenced via an xpath that stays the same for the life of the test)?

Comment: Yes there is a constant xpath I can use

Answer (score 1):

I haven't ever done this, but you might be able to use the listener interface to call a function before or after every keyword. For example, the listener might look something like this (untested):

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

xpath = //*[@id='loading_element']

class CustomListener(object):
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2

    def start_keyword(self, name, attrs):
        selib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance("SeleniumLibrary")
        selib.wait_until_element_is_not_visible(xpath)
```

This may throw an exception if the element doesn't exist on the current page, and you also need to add code to handle the case where a keyword runs before the browser is open, but hopefully it gives the general idea.

For more information about the listener interface see the section titled [Listener Interface](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface) in the [Robot Framework User Guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html).

Answer (score 0):

Another direction you could take is to use the [SeleniumLibrary](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Execute%20Async%20Javascript) keyword `Execute Async Javascript`.

The document states:

> Executes asynchronous JavaScript code.
>
> Similar to Execute Javascript except that scripts executed with this
>   keyword must explicitly signal they are finished by invoking the
>   provided callback. This callback is always injected into the executed
>   function as the last argument.
>
> Scripts must complete within the script timeout or this keyword will
>   fail

With the following code example from the docs:

```
${result} = Execute Async JavaScript    
... var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1]; 
... function answer(){callback("text");};   
... window.setTimeout(answer, 2000);    
Should Be Equal ${result}   text
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution I ended up using :)
Worked well, thank you for all comments and help!

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
from datetime import datetime

class LoaderListener(object):
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = "GLOBAL"

    def __init__(self):
        self.ROBOT_LIBRARY_LISTENER = self
        self.selib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance("SeleniumLibrary")

    def _start_suite(self, name, attrs):
        BuiltIn().log_to_console("Loader Listener Has Been Attached.")


    def start_keyword(self, name, attrs):
        try:

            # If this doesn't fail we have the loader
            self.selib.find_element("id=loader")

            # Take time stamp for when we begin waiting
            BuiltIn().log_to_console("The Page Is Loading.")
            start_time = datetime.now()

            # Wait Until Element Not Visible
            # Sometimes this will fail, because by the time we get here the loader is gone.
            # In that case, just continue as normal
            try:
                self.selib.wait_until_element_is_not_visible("id=loader") 
            except:
                pass

            # Take time stamp for when we have stopped waiting
            end_time = datetime.now()      

            # Calculate time elapsed
            elapsed_time = (end_time-start_time)

            # Create output message and log to conosle
            output_message = "The Page Has Finished Loading in {0}".format(elapsed_time)
            BuiltIn().log_to_console(output_message)

        except:
            # We don't have the element...
            pass
```